# SalesForce DML set-based operations and atomic transactions

Tags: salesforce

I have just begun to read about Salesforce APEX and its DML.  It seems you can do bulk updates by constructing a list, adding items to be updated to the list, and then issuing an `update myList` call.

Does such an invocation of `update` create an atomic transaction, so that if for any reason an update to one of the items in the list should fail, the entire update operation is rolled back?  If not, is there a way to wrap an update in an atomic transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole context is an atomic transaction. By the time Apex code runs SF has already started, whether it's a Visualforce button click, a trigger or any other entry point. If you hit a validation error, null <strike>pointer</strike> reference exception, attempt to divide by zero, thrown exception etc - whole thing will be rolled back.

`update myList;` works in "all or nothing" mode. If one of records fails on validation rule required field missing etc - you'll get an exception. You can wrap it in a try-catch block but still - whole list just failed to load.

If you need "save what you can" behavio(u)r - read up about `Database.update()` version of this call. It takes optional parameter that lets you do exactly that.

Last but not least if you're inserting complex scenarios (insert account, insert contacts, one of contacts fails but you had that in try-catch so the account saved OK so what now, do you have to manually delete it? Weak...) you have `Database.setSavepoint()` and `Database.rollback()` calls.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9410/rolling-back-dml-operation-in-apex-method

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the additional helpful links!